# I cannot add script to my player in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

"You are trying to replace or create a Prefab from the instance 'Carbine' that references a missing script. This is not allowed.
Please change the script or remove it from the GameObject."

I tried renaming the script. But nothing working out. Does anyone know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the prefab in the hierarchy and looking for the script on the attached components. Try removing any scripts that are on there, and re-adding them by dragging them from the project window back onto the prefab in the inspector.

Let me know if that works.